# Exporting emails from an Outlook subfolder to Excel

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I've found a VBA macro that takes e-mails from Outlook and put them into cells in Excel. 
The code works, but  I want to tell Excel only to get e-mails from a specific subfolder. In my Inbox-folder I have a subfolder called Info. I want to be able to get e-mails from this subfolder.

This is the code that I have now:

```
Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
Dim folders As Outlook.folders
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim Pst_Folder_Name
Dim MailboxName



'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
MailboxName = "My email address"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

Set folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailboxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name)
If folder = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
    GoTo end_lbl1:
End If

'Rad Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
Sheets(1).Activate

For iRow = 1 To folder.Items.Count
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1).Select
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderEmailAddress
    'Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
Next iRow
MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"

end_lbl1:

End Sub
```

How can I make sure that it gets emails from the subfolder, and not the mainfolder?

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Thanks for clarifying. I'm new to this and was just frustrated that my embarrasing tries didn't work out. Thank you for taking the time to making this clear to me, I now see that my question seemed like I wanted someone to do the work for me rather than try myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
MailboxName = "My email address"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox"

' subfolder name
Dim subFolderName As String
subFolderName = "Info"

Set folder = Outlook.Session.folders(MailboxName).folders(Pst_Folder_Name).Folders(subFoldersName)
If folder = "" Then
   MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
   GoTo end_lbl1:
End If
```

Also you may consider using the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to get a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems kind of simple now that I see it - I tried with enumarating folders and stuff that didn't really make much sense to me, so thanks for your help. I was going crazy over this.

Comment: can i get mail log list for specific date from outlook based on condition